# How much space does elasticsearch bulkinsert take up in write thread queue?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, queue, elastic-stack

When bulk inserting 400,000 documents in Elasticsearch, multiple write threads are working simultaneously,
One write thread runs when bulkinsert 1000 documents.

Depending on the size of the bulk insert, it seems to be internally divided into several tasks and loaded into the waiting queue. Is my prediction correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this two API may help you:

```
GET _cat/thread_pool?help
GET _cat/thread_pool/write?v
```